# SQL query (using joins) / recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 3 tables: AuditCheckCriteria as T1, Learners as T2 & LearnerAuditRegistrations as T3 with the following structure:

```
  T1: CheckID     CheckName                      
          1       'Stage One'
          2       'Stage Two'
          3       'Stage Three'

  T2   LearnerID   LearnerName
          10         'John'
          11         'Peter'
          12         'Paul'

  T3: LearnerAuditID  LearnerID  CheckID
          1             10         1
          2             10         2
          3             11         1
          4             11         2
          5             11         3
```

I want the following output:

```
T2.LearnerID, T1.CheckID, T3.CheckID
      10           1           1
      10           2           2
      10           3          NULL
      11           1           1
      11           2           2
      11           3           3
      12           1          NULL
      12           2          NULL
      12           3          NULL
```

(T2 & T3 contain over 20000 rows each)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What part of the query are you having difficulty with? You have presented requirements, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want all combinations of values from T1 and T2, with the lookup from T3.  If so, the following does this:

```
with t1vals as (select distinct checkID from t1),
     t2vals as (select distinct LearnerId from t2)
select t2vals.LearnerId, t1vals.CheckId, t3.CheckId
from t1vals cross join
     t2vals left outer join
     t3
     on t3.LearnerId = t2vals.LearnerId and
        t3.CheckId = t1vals.CheckId
```

Answer (score 0):

Use (T2 cross join T1) left join T3..